# nginx proxy page not found

Tags: apache, tomcat, nginx, proxy

I have a web service hosted on local ip 192.168.1.21:8080 (Apache Tomcat) which is up and running (ie I can surf to that IP and get the tomcat front page as expected).

I'm now trying to set up a proxy rule in my nginx saying that the url "jft.pdf.home.se" should redirect to that ip (using below nginx proxy rule:)

```
 # GeneratePDF
server{
      listen 80;
      server_name jft.pdf.home.se;

      #GeneratePDF
      location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.1.21:8080/;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
      }
}
```

When I try to surf to jft.pdf.home.se I get page cannot be found error. Again, if I use 192.168.1.21:8080, it works fine.

I also tried changing server_name to pdf.home.se but with the same result.

Can anyone see what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I soon realized that I hadn't posted this DNS yet which was what caused the page not found!